# Search for text files in a directory and append a (static) line to each of them

Tags: linux, bash, file-io, sed, grep

I have a directory with many subdirectories and files with suffixes in those subdirectories (e.g `FileA-suffixA FileB-SuffixB FileC-SuffixC FileD-SuffixA`, etc).

How can I recursively search for files with a certain suffix, and append a user-defined line of text to those files? I feel like this is a job for grep and sed, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing it. I'm fairly new to scripting, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like

```
find /where/to/search -type f -iname '*.SUFFIX' -exec echo "USER DEFINED STRING" >> \{\} \;
```

1. `find` searches in the suplied path
2. `-type f` finds only files
3. `-iname '*.SUFFIX'` find the .SUFFIXed names, case ignored

Comment: i'm trying to understand how this works. what does -type f do?

Comment: does this auto-recurse through subdirectories? or do i need an -r or an argument like that?

Answer (score 1):

```
find ./ -name "*suffix" -exec bash -c 'echo "line_to_add" >> $1' -- {} \;
```

Basically you use find to get a list of the files. Then you use bash to echo append your line to that list.

Comment: what does "$1' -- {} \;" do?

Comment: I got this working by hacking together some samples and some knowledge I have, so I can't be 100% definitive. But, $1 is the 1st set of data (in this case the list of files). the -- is to say there are no more options to bash (such as -c, -X). I don't know what the {} \; are accomplishing here. It might work without them.

Comment: I would've just done this in actual Bash or Perl. That's my personal opinion though.